How to compare preceding row with current row in SQL
I have a query like this. Now I want add a one more column using this Excel formula. However I cannot achieve this with rows unbounded preceding. I really need some help in this.
WITH cte_Main AS
(
    SELECT Theater, Parts, Open_Orders, Non_Restricted_Empty_Bins
    FROM Apps.Fill_Rate
    ORDER BY Parts
)
SELECT
    ms.*,
    IF (parts previous row = parts present row then previous result of rpr_order_consumption - non_restricted_bins, open_orders - non_restricted_bins as Rpr_order_consumption
FROM
    cte_main;

Now this formula is kind of Excel now I want try this in SQL.
Sample data:


please have a look on LAG/LEAD-functions

Also, please don’t use images in your questions, always use editable text, appropriately formatted, so that someone can copy it if they want to try out a solution

Thanks Sergey. I tried the Lag function but I'm getting 0 in rpr order consumption instead the desired result. I can share the data set in appropriate format to use, could you please share a query I can work with please.

lag/lead is the correct way to accomplish this, but you haven't provided enough information for us to help you.  How do you order your rows, for example.  In Excel, they are ordered.  In SQL, they are not.  When using lag/lead, you must order them in a way that is unique by record.  How do you accomplish that with your data?

This question was closed, but we can still help you - if you ask a new question, and this time include sample data and desired results that make easier for us trying to help to reproduce.
